when I run anchor test using rust test case I can not see the std out print;
The code like  println!("Your transaction signature {}", tx); cannot work in my test case.
I use anchor test they can finish the test and success but can not print msg I want.

You want to use the msg! macro to print in Anchor, and they will appear in .anchor/program-logs after you run anchor test, unless there is an error to print to the console, then they will only be in console instead.
